# Backup up a computer at a specific point

Tags: windows-10, backup, windows-backup

I understand the concept of backing up files, but lets say I love my computer setup the way it is right now, driver settings, desktop background, shortcuts. Everything is just humming nicely. And then i accidentally destroy my hard drive. Is there a tool that would allow me to restore it to that exact point without reloading the OS and transferring the files, etc? I am running Windows 10.

Comment: Hundreds of drive imaging software exists.  Clonezilla,drbl,acronis, and etc just to name a few.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Yes, there are tools to do that.  They make a clone or image of the hard disk, which includes everything exactly as it is.  Asking for specific product recommendations is off-topic, but if you Google cloning or disk imaging software you will get endless options and reviews.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe there are Windows Backups that will allow you to restore some volumes, but I can only speak from my current setup and what I am experienced with and that's performing a Bare Metal Restore from a specific point in time using Storage Craft's Shadow Protect. I believe most other backup vendors especially the free ones, only restore block level data changes not so much from a volume based restore such as you mentioned.

If your hard drive was completely destroyed, you would want to get a new drive in the machine and boot into the shadow protect iso and from there perform a shadow protect bare metal restore from the specific point in time that has backed up. You will have to know a little bit about partitioning to make sure the machine is restored properly.

You can get a Free NAS or other specific NAS appliance on your network which you can take backups to and zfs snapshots will be taken of these shares and maintain a backup chain as such (in case ransom ware infected the shares let's say)and perform regular backups of your Win10 machine on a regular schedule.

There are many routes you can go, but for what you mentioned this would be the best bet. If let's say you lost some files, and don't want to blow away the whole OS for restore, you may want to look into just backing up the block level data and performing iSCSI restores later.

*"Is there a tool that would allow me to restore it to that exact point without reloading the OS and transferring the files, etc?"*

The simple answer is no, because if your hard drive was destroyed as you put it, then even BMR'ing from a backup would have to restore the OS. No disk, no boot record(s).

Also, just note that you do not HAVE to backup to a NAS or other external device, that's just a suggestion I made based on my current setup.

http://www.shadowprotect.com/
http://www.freenas.org/